# sort `caret` models in `bwplot()`

Tags: r, sorting, r-caret, bwplot

I am plotting box-plots of the accuracy scores of resamples of yearly models trained with `caret`.
The models are named by the years they refer to: 2000, 2001, 2002, ..., 2010.
I want the models to appear in the box-plots with ascending order based on the year i.e. name of the model.

The summary of resamples based on the below code

```
fit.year.res <- resamples(fit.year)
summary(fit.year.res)
```

looks like this:

[image]

But then, the different yearly models in the box plot are not sorted:

```
scales <- list(x=list(relation="free"), y=list(relation="free"))
bwplot(fit.year.res, scales=scales)
```

[image]

I have tried converting the models element of resamples `fit.year.res$models` to factor from character, but it didn't make nay difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of an easy solution using `bwplot` method from caret package. Perhaps there is one but my lattice skills are lacking. I recommend plotting the boxplots manually using ggplot2. This way you will have much better control over the final plot.

Since you did not post an example with data I will use one of the examples from `?caret:::bwplot.resamples`

```
library(caret)
library(party)
library(RWeka)

load(url("http://topepo.github.io/caret/exampleModels.RData"))

resamps <- resamples(list(CART = rpartFit,
                          CondInfTree = ctreeFit,
                          MARS = earthFit))

bwplot(resamps,
       metric = "RMSE")
```

produces:

[image]

To make the plot manually using ggplot you will need some data manipulation:

```
library(tidyverse)
resamps$values %>% #extract the values
  select(1, ends_with("RMSE")) %>% #select the first column and all columns with a name ending with "RMSE"
  gather(model, RMSE, -1) %>% #convert to long table
  mutate(model = sub("~RMSE", "", model)) %>% #leave just the model names
  ggplot()+ #call ggplot
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = RMSE, y = model)) -> p1 #and plot the box plot

p1
```

[image]

To set a specific order on the y axis:

```
p1 +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("MARS", "CART", "CondInfTree"))
```

[image]

If you prefer lattice

```
library(lattice)

resamps$values %>%
  select(1, ends_with("RMSE")) %>%
  gather(model, RMSE, -1) %>%
  mutate(model = sub("~RMSE", "", model)) %>%
  {bwplot(model ~ RMSE, data = .)}
```

[image]

to change the order change the levels of model (this approach also works with ggplot2):

```
resamps$values %>%
  select(1, ends_with("RMSE")) %>%
  gather(model, RMSE, -1) %>%
  mutate(model = sub("~RMSE", "", model),
         model = factor(model, levels = c("MARS", "CART", "CondInfTree"))) %>%
    {bwplot(model ~ RMSE, data = .)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The function `bwplot.resamples` is used to generate this plot and if you look at the [underlying code](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/src/R/resamples.R), the variables are factorized based on their average performance under the metric of interest.

Below I have the relevant code that does the factorization:

```
bwplot.resamples <- function (x, data = NULL, models = x$models, metric = x$metric, ...)
{
....
  avPerf <- ddply(subset(plotData, Metric == metric[1]),
                  .(Model),
                  function(x) c(Median = median(x$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
  avPerf <- avPerf[order(avPerf$Median),]

    ......
}
```

I guess what you need to do is to make the plot manually:

```
data(BloodBrain)
gbmFit <- train(bbbDescr[,-3], logBBB,"gbm",tuneLength=6,
            trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"),verbose=FALSE)
     
glmnetFit <- train(bbbDescr[,-3], logBBB,"glmnet",tuneLength=6,
            trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

rfFit <- train(bbbDescr[,-3], logBBB,"rf",tuneLength=6,
            trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

knnFit <- train(bbbDescr[,-3], logBBB,"knn",tuneLength=6,
            trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

resamps <- resamples(list(gbm = gbmFit,glmnet=glmnetFit,knn=knnFit,rf=rfFit))
```

If you plot, you can see they are sorted according to the medians (the solid dot):

```
bwplot(resamps,metric="MAE")
```

[image]

You can access the values under $values and make a function to plot it, something like below:

```
plotMet = function(obj,metric,var_order){

mat = obj$values
mat = mat[,grep(metric,colnames(mat))]
colnames(mat) = gsub("[~][^ ]*","",colnames(mat))
boxplot(mat[,var_order],horizontal=TRUE,las=2,xlab=metric)

}

plotMet(resamps,"MAE",c("rf","knn","gbm","glmnet"))
```

[image]

Also not a very good idea to name your models with numbers.. try something like model_2000, model_2001 etc